# e.Row.Attributes not working after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i used  this code for set ID Row of GridView :

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("id", "me" & e.Row.RowIndex)

    End If
```

to use with JavaScript and it work first time but after any postback not working

Answer (score 1):

Where is this code placed? Seems to be in the GridView_RowDataBound event?
If it works the first time, and after a postback it does not work, I would check if your javascript code is loaded after a postback.
We need a little more information to help you.

Comment: Yes i place in GridView_RowDataBound and first time it work fine but after postback not work and i check  page source the ID for Tr not created after posback

Comment: OK, then this is your problem.

Comment: The code that is setting the ID to the TR is executed only the first time and in the next postbacks is not executed. Normally this is because of setting [Grid.Datasource = AnyDatasource] inside an [If Not Page.IsPostBack Then ...] Try to put the [Grid.Datasource = AnyDatasource] outside of the IF, to check if it works...

Comment: yes , I put grigview inside UpdatePanel now . If i disable UpdatePanel or put grid outside UpdatePanel is works for any postpack